# What will happen if I don't purchase a signed SSL certificate for my website?

Tags: ssl, certificate

I don't use SSL on my website currently. It's a small hobby site with no online store or anything of that nature that would need it. I've read that Google Chrome will stop loading such sites sometime in the near future. Are there going to be additional future consequences if I don't purchase a signed SSL certificate?

Comment: Besides other browser vendors making similar decisions?

Comment: You don't need to purchase one. You can get a free one from https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Sigh. Here is my web host's opinion of Let's Encrypt: https://www.webhostingpad.com/ssl/#letsencrypt Quote: "blah blah blah... we do not allow Let's Encrypt SSLs on our servers—for your own protection." They of course offer their own, paid solution.

Comment: @posfan12 so find another host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you are saying, I believe `SSL` is not necessary for your website, but it is always better to secure it with an `SSL certificate` if you don't want popular browsers to block its access!

I would recommend you to use [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) to serve your website in `https`. `letsencrypt` provides you with a free `ssl certificate` that is valid for 90 days.

If you host the static files of your website on `AWS`, you can get your certificate from `AWS certificate manager`, this is also a [solution](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/certificate-manager/).

Comment: This is good news! I thought I was SOL. I will have to do some further research to get it installed and working.

Comment: Do the major browsers recognize this certificate as coming from a trusted CA?  Otherwise, you'll still get "blocked" (Chrome will let you browse HTTP sites; it will just say that they're unsafe, and make you agree to be unsafe before it will let you browse them.  Same with non-CA certificates).

Comment: @RobertHarvey letsencrypt is not a toy CA. Its purpose is to allow everyone to use SSL, so that eventually all traffic can be https. It's hard for Chrome to decide to block non-https sites, if the majority of sites don't want to invest money for ssl certificates. https://letsencrypt.org/2018/08/06/trusted-by-all-major-root-programs.html

Comment: @Kayaman: OK, but is it a *first-class certificate?*  There is software in operating systems like Windows Server that will create SSL certificates, and they will properly encrypt your HTTP traffic, but the browsers will warn you that it doesn't come from a certified CA.

Comment: @RobertHarvey see the link I gave for trust details, among other things "Our root is now trusted by all major root programs, including Microsoft, Google, Apple, Mozilla, Oracle, and Blackberry.".

Comment: @Kayaman: Good to know, thanks.

Comment: Whoa.  *Only 90 days?*

Comment: @RobertHarvey you're an expert on this site, it's not hard for you to check how letsencrypt works instead of showing off uninformedness. The certificates are auto-renewed, so C00kieMonsta's answer is a bit misleading in that area.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner the auto-renewal of letsencrypt does not happen out of the box when you ask for a certificate, you need to set up a bot that will take care of asking for a new certificate when needed... I use such bots on my EC2 instances to renew the certificate every 60 days. More info: https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianstretch-apache , moreover posfan12 is not asking how for a setup in particular...

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner: Forgive me for being uninformed, but it's been awhile (read: never) since I've had to provision a CA cert for a site.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that should have been tongue-in-cheek. Your expertise is highly appreciated :-)

Comment: @RobertHarvey By the way, this very site uses a Let's Encrypt certificate, so you can just look up at the URL bar to see if your browser trusts it.

Comment: @8bittree: That would only work if I could also see the certificate.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think most browsers should be able to show you the certificate, likely beginning with a click on the lock icon in the URL bar. Firefox and Vivaldi definitely can.

Comment: @8bittree: Yes, that works.  Thanks.